# MvvmCross Portable Class Library - System.Net.ServicePointManager

Tags: c#, mvvmcross, portable-class-library, system.net

In my PCL I am trying to call to an SSL service so I am trying to set ServerCertificateValidationCallback like so:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertficate;
```

but it seems I can't add a reference to System.Net in my PCL and it says the type ServicePointManager does not exist.

How do I reference this in my PCL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't reference this in your pcl - it isn't defined in any current portable subset.

If you need to use it, you can reference it in some of your Ui projects - eg in your setup class - or for reuse you can build a plugin to reference it for some platforms. However there are some modern platforms which simply don't support it - WindowsPhone (and perhaps windows store too?)

For more on injecting platform specific code into pcl core libraries, see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/n31-injection-platform-specific.html

Comment: I was only doing this to get beyond the error thrown when developing locally since it doesn't trust my self-signed cert. Of course once I move the pertinent web service to TEST and PROD, that will not be an issue. I suppose I can just disable SSL for development purposes.

Thanks Stuart - Great job with MvvmCross by the way. Stellar stuff.